# Регулярные выражения Буквы

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Как в Java 8 оставлять только буквы и числа всех алфавитов, используя регулярные выражения? либо другим способом. К примеру, такой кода

```
String s = "Hello, world. Привет 異體字 мир 123 456 789 "+ "\n" +"~d!f@q#t$.%^&*()`☻";
String e = s.replaceAll("[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9]", " ");
```

обрежет также и 異體字, которые необходимо оставить. есть вариант не перчислять все кодировки?
(по типу A-Za-z)

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я помню, в <kbd>Java8</kbd> regexp есть поддержка `\p` подробнее: [www.regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

```java
String s = "Hello, world. Привет 異體字 мир 123 456 789 "+ "\n" +"~d!f@q#t$.%^&*()`☻";
String e = s.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{N}]+", " ");
```

Результатом будет:

```txt
Hello world Привет 異體字 мир 123 456 789 d f q t
```

Если убрать квантификатор `+` то результат будет выглядеть так

```txt
Hello  world  Привет 異體字 мир 123 456 789   d f q t
```

---

`\p{L}` или `\p{Letter}` - любые буквы любого языка
`\p{N}` или `\p{Number}` - любые виды цифровых символов в любых языках
Подробнее: [wikipedia.org](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд вам проще всего составить регулярное выражение не с охватом диапазонов, а наоборот, с исключением ненужных символов.

```
[^`~!@"#№;$%^:?&*()_\-+=\/+{\[\]}\\|;"'<,>.?,]
```

Но, конечно, надо смотреть на ситуацию. Возможно, такой вариант вам тоже не подойдёт, потому что введено может быть реально что угодно. Тогда используйте unicode-диапазоны, в частности для иероглифов: [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585914/matching-chinese-characters-with-regular-expressions-php).

Comment: но только с латинским алфавитом

Comment: @roman_ хм, и правда. Сейчас дополню ответ.

Answer (score 0):

можно так

```
String regex="([A-z]||[А-я]||[0-9]||,||!||\\.||\\?|| )*"; //принимает латиницу, кирилцу, знаки припинания( "." "," "!" "?") и пробел   в любом порядке и в любом количестве. 
String text="Hyffюю, .?!"; 
text.matches(regex) ;//даный метод сверяет текст с регулярным выражением если схожи то возрашаит true иначи false
```